# Script# Syntax for a Post Message Event Listener

Tags: script#

Does anyone know how to write the following JavaScript in Script#? Without using the `Script.Literal` function.

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) { var message = e.data; alert(message); })
```

Answer (score 0):

OK if someone else needs to do this here is how i got it to work.

From the child iframe  do a post message

```
window.parent.postMessage(msg, '*');
```

then in the Script# add the listener like this

```
Window.AddEventListener("message", delegate(ElementEvent @event)
{

    // do something with data here

}, false);
```